# Impact of Phone Display on x,y coordinates

Tags: android, graphics

I am trying to decipher why a point at the same position on different Android phone screens can return such different results.  I placed a dot on the approximate same position on two different screens (Android Essential and Samsung Galaxy S7):

**Essential**

```
physicalHeight: [2279] 
screenHeight: [1920]
y value extracted from MotionEvent: [616.0]
```

**Galaxy S7**

```
physicalHeight: [2560]
screenHeight: [1920]
y value extracted from MotionEvent:: [770.25]
```

What am I not taking into account in that the y position on these two phones are almost 150 points different even though the position is approximately the same on both phones and as you can tell from the height values, the phones are approximately the same height?

Comment: What designated the approximate same position? Please explain exactly what experiment you did. How did you place the dot and what did you measure?

Comment: It was an MotionEvent.ACTION_UP of a user picking their finger off the screen in the approximately the same position on two different phones.

Comment: Again, how do you determine that two positions on different phones are approximately the same?

Comment: Because the underlying visual that the user is moving their finger against is the same.  So, if I look at the screenHeight value of both phones, they are exactly the same so the y value extracted from the MotionEvent should also be the same (or within a small CEP).

Comment: And that visual is a fullscreen image that you display on both phones? Or what is it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.